# Fuel carried by current Crew Dragon

Tags: spacex, crewed-spaceflight

How much fuel weight will the current Crew Dragon carry? Will it be just enough for launch abort, or the full load (over 3000 lbs) needed for propulsive landing as a back-up to the parachutes?

I have seen different statements as to whether propulsive landing capability will be retained for parachute back-up.

The 3000 lbs estimate is from [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/16814/12102) about the early Dragon2. It was used for the pad abort test, but I'm almost certain this carried a full (propulsive) fuel load for thorough data collection.

Comment: The 3000 lb figure is from this thread, for the early Dragon2. Was used for the pad abort test, but I'm almost certain this carried a full (propulsive) fuel load for thorough data collection.

Comment: Sorry, link I referred to is https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16813/dragon-2-propellant-capacity .

Comment: I've made an edit and included your information back into the original post. It's always better to do that than to leave comments, because they are considered temporary and can be cleaned up some time in the future.

Comment: I can't exactly prove a negative, but to my knowledge there has been zero official mention of propulsive backups for parachutes. I know the community likes this idea (I even see the appeal), but the reality is parachutes are incredibly reliable, and already redundant. And in the unlikely event there was a chute failure, the capsule has a good chance of being entangled and in a bad attitude for propulsive landing anyway. I think we should take them at face value that propulsive landing is not happening, period.