# Dragon Superdracos: how much MMH/NTO propellant?

Tags: falcon-9, dragon, monopropellant, super-draco, hydrazine

How much [Monomethylhydrazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomethylhydrazine) + [Dinitrogen tetroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitrogen_tetroxide)
 (MMH/NTO) hypergolic propellant does the Dragon crew module carry and how much burn time does that afford them during launch escape if one is triggered?

Answer (score 1):

For the abort tests in early 2020, [according to documents filed with the FAA over a year prior](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ast/environmental/nepa_docs/review/launch/media/Draft_EA_for_SpaceX_In-flight_Dragon_Abort_508.pdf), the Dragon flew with 2565 kg of propellant (1590 kg of NTO  and 975 kg of MMH), but only about half of that was fired during the abort.

Consumption rate for a single SuperDraco is about 31 kg/s (= 71kN thrust / 2300 m/s exhaust velocity), so for the suite of 8 thrusters, 2565 kg of propellant would last about 10 seconds.

The actual current figures could be quite a bit different from that.

Comment: Thank you, Russell! This is super helpful. So I take it the combustion ratio would be 1.59 NTO to 0.975 MMH by mass?

Comment: Seems like, though at 1.63:1 that's a richer mix [than the 2.17:1 WP suggests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_rocket_propellant#Bipropellants).

Comment: Ah! You know, 1.63 is super close to the 1.65 NTO/MMH density ratio, meaning you'd burn 1:1 NTO/MMH by volume, so you'd burn almost exactly one tank of NTO for every tank of MMH if the tanks were identical (as they seem to be from pictures I've seen).

Comment: Thank you for using metric units :D

Comment: Interesting. Most spacecraft using similar propellant combinations have asymmetrical tanks to optimize the mixture ratio for performance ([Transtage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transtage), and the [Apollo LM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Module) ascent stage's "cheeks" being two cases where it's externally apparent). It would be a little odd if volume symmetry won out in Dragon.

Comment: Do you happen to know how many MMH tanks and how many NTO tanks Dragon carries? There are 12 compartments each big enough to carry a tank, and I've seen pictures showing eight red tanks and either two or four gray tanks, but I'm suddenly not sure. I always figured the red tanks were fuel and the gray tanks were maybe oxygen for the crew, so that would make it four NTO tanks and four MMH tanks---although at the dimensions I used in my model, I would need closer to five tanks of each to match that amount of fuel...

Comment: ...Although the 1388 kg total propellant mentioned in https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16813/dragon-2-propellant-capacity?rq=1 would fit nicely in my eight tanks... Still, if those eight tanks carry just enough for <10 s superdraco burn time, where would the fuel for the draco RCS thrusters come from? Did they just figure if they have to eject, they no longer need the RCS, so it's OK to run out of fuel for it?

Comment: I don't know anything about its tankage. Shared propellant would make sense; in a nominal mission plan, they don't use the Superdracos at all, while in an abort, little or no RCS would be needed. During the escape burn, the ship is passively stabilized by the fins on the trunk, but they might need a few seconds RCS to reorient the ship tail-first for parachute deployment and splashdown, after the trunk is dropped.

It might be worth hunting down newer documentation for the Crew Dragon.